# port forwarding django development server - URL is being doubled

Tags: python, django, centos, django-dev-server

I have a Django development server running on a remote centos VM on another lan. I have set up port forwarding using Secure CRT to access the web page through my browser from my desk pc. I am currently not using apache with the development server and is shutdown.

I start the server by running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`.

When I type either the ip or `www.localhost.com` into the web browser, my URL is read as if it has been doubled with the host being read as if it was also the path.

```
Page not found (404)##
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.localhost.com/http://www.localhost.com/
```

When I try to access the development server from within the same LAN the page loads up fine.

I have been searching through the django documentation and stack overflow, but I have yet to find a similar problem to this. Does anyone have any thoughts on why this may be happening and what could be a possible solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the request URL is incorrect:
**http://www.localhost.com/http://www.localhost.com/** should probably be **http://*actual_machine_IP*.com/**

I'd start searching there. You won't be able to access the VM's port 80 from a different lan using localhost as the hostname since localhost is **probably** already set in your hosts file.

If you want to test your dev environ remotely, can I suggest either setting up Apache properly with port 80 (as opposed to using django's dev server--privilege restrictions and all that can be circumvented with sudo and other bad practice) or use a pre-built shared dev service like **vagrant share**.